# How to debug boot loop?

Tags: samsung, twrp, boot-loop, lineageos, diagnostics

I have a boot looping Samsung Galaxy S4 Mini LTE (also known as GT-i9195 or `serranoltexx` – this is not GT-i9195i or `serranoveltexx`).

**Current behavior:** when the phone is off, pressing power button results to normal boot screen with usual yellow text in the top left corner about custom kernel ("Set Warranty Bit : kernel"). The screen stays in this view for around 20 seconds, turns to black, vibration motor runs for two short periods and the system reboots. I guess the system is failing to boot until hardware watchdog resets the system due timeout exeeding. If I boot with <kbd>Volume down</kbd> + <kbd>Home</kbd> + <kbd>Power</kbd> held, the phone enters into download mode as usual. And if I boot with <kbd>Volume up</kbd> + <kbd>Home</kbd> + <kbd>Power</kbd> held, the phone enters recovery mode (TWRP version 3.3.1.0) where everything seems to work as usual, too. I was running LineageOS 16 (Android 9.0) with SELinux enforcement enabled with June 2019 security patches. The system has `XXUCOL3` modem firmware if I remember correctly.

In the end, I can successfully boot into download mode and into TWRP recovery. However, the system started to fail to boot to normal system after normal shutdown-restart cycle and the system was working okay before shutdown. **Is there any way to diagnose and possibly fix the problem without wiping all the data?**

Steps that I've already tried:

- Wiping Art/Dalwik Cache, Cache partition and System partition and re-installing full system image via TWRP.
- Removing battery
- Booting with SIM card and sdcard removed

I really want to understand why this happened to avoid it in the future. I really don't want to have a device that randomly enters this state and the only way to fix it is to wipe the whole device. Being able to bring the current system to usable state without full wipe would be a nice bonus because it avoids reconfiguring all the settings and apps again.

<sub>And yes, I know this device is old and I had to previously replace motherboard due emmc chip failing but I really like the form factor and no vendor is nowadays providing similar device. If Sharp Aquos R2 compact didn't have notches on the screen it would be my next phone.</sub>

Comment: This may be caused by software error in the latest version of ROM I'm using: https://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s4-mini/orig-development/rom-lineageos-16-0-s4-mini-t3833063/page86 - other people are also reporting about issues that system no longer boots up after power off. No fix is known yet other than wiping all data.

Comment: See the answer below. It turned out that it was fixable via adb in TWRP without wiping data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In practice, the only way to debug early boot loops is to [read the kernel log](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=79757966&postcount=875) as follows:

**Minimum steps to get the kernel log if you have a working adb and TWRP:**

1. When the device is boot looping, press and hold VOLUME UP + HOME until the boot loop repeats and you get blue "RECOVERY" text in top left corner (specific key sequence will differ depending on actual harware but above should correct for Samsung devices). The important part is that you have to enter the TWRP recovery directly after failed boot and exact steps to do this depend on the hardware. The above example should be correct for all Samsung devices with hardware home button. The firmware may have some other indication about entering recovery partition than blue "RECOVERY" text which I think is part of Samsung's firmware implementation.
2. Attach the phone to computer using an USB cable and wait for TWRP to finish booting (the order you attach the phone vs starting TWRP booting is not important).
3. Extract the kernel log from failed boot. Run following on the host computer command line:

The required command for linux host:

```
adb shell cat /proc/last_kmsg > ~/Desktop/boot-loop-kernel-log.txt
```

The required command for Windows host:

```
adb shell cat /proc/last_kmsg > %UserProfile%/Desktop/boot-loop-kernel-log.txt
```

You'll end up with a file called `boot-loop-kernel-log.txt` on your desktop which contains the kernel log of failed boot.

This works because `/proc/last_kmsg` contains the memory contents of previous boot kernel log ring (this works because kernel keeps this log in known memory address and next boot saves the contents of that memory area before writing the new log in the same location). Some vendors put the previous boot kernel log ring to file `/sys/fs/pstore/console-ramoops` or `cat /sys/fs/pstore/console-ramoops-0` so you may need to do

```
adb shell cat '/sys/fs/pstore/console-ramoops*' > ~/Desktop/boot-loop-kernel-log.txt
```

instead, but the idea is still the same. Obviously, if the firmware overwrites all memory with zeros on boot, this cannot work.

In my specific boot looping case the problem was caused by "Live Display" color correction failing during boot process if its settings had been changed from the default. [With that specific problem, the workaround was to boot to recovery and execute following as root](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=80042629&postcount=964)

```
rm /data/vendor/display/.displaymodedefault
```

Long version of instructions to acquire boot log during a boot loop: https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1520508

Comment: and if android doesn’t reach the point where it can connect to adb ?

Comment: Android `recovery` mode uses *different* boot partition than the normal boot so you should be able to get into TWRP which provides the ADB support. If you have e.g. flashed wrong ROM (technically flashed the OS partition but Android fans calls this "ROM" for some reason) *and also* flashed wrong recovery code, then you cannot follow above steps. Some hardware (e.g. modern Qualcomm) support booting recovery image over USB cable using `fastboot` mode. For wrong boot+recovery, I would recommend searching for `brick recovery` combined with your hardware name (e.g. `gt-i9195`).

Comment: No, what I’m meaning is I already have access to `/data` partition but don’t find anything usefull there. Also Samsung doesn’t have ᴛᴡʀᴘ in recovery mode.

Comment: Obviously, Samsung *official fimware* doesn't have a real recovery mode. If you have official firmware installed and the system boot loops, it will be much harder to debug. I guess you could install TWRP on the recovery partition and follow above steps. Note that you may need to *mount* the data partition in TWRP before you can actually see your data. Some versions of TWRP do this by default, some (which I consider safer to use) do not mount data automatically. Note that if you have locked bootloader, you cannot install TWRP when the system is boot looping and factory reset is only option.

Comment: I m in the same hell . Something poisoned my phone into `boot loop` stuck at `powered by android` logo. POsted my Q here          `https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/239500/analyzing-boot-loop-root-cause-from-console-ramoops-0-logcat`  &  w link to entire `kernel log aka ramoops` in there. can some dev take a peep to see if there's a quick fix or I am going to have to start with a clean slate

Comment: thanks bud for peeping into the issue. As I found out  `/data` could be restored ( see update with findings ) but stuck with bootloop   this question (  `https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/239500/analyzing-boot-loop-root-cause-from-console-ramoops-0-logcat` )  this question carrying a `bounty` might be of intrest  if you  are   that 'colonel' of  `kernel`.  Like  you correctly said need N and F `boot` logs  & I got 'em both in there